# Safely accessing the this pointer in a class-member coroutine

Tags: c++, coroutine

The problem is that the object may be destroyed before the coroutine finishes.

I've already solved this problem by using C++/WinRT tools. But I'm interested in how you could solve it with the c++ standard library.

The problem has been shamelessly repurposed from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references

```cpp
struct MyClass
{
    std::string m_value{ "Hello, World!" };

    Task<std::string> RetrieveValueAsync()
    {
        co_await 5s; // resumes on thread pool
        co_return m_value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto instance = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    auto async = instance->RetrieveValueAsync();
    instance = nullptr; // Simulate the class instance going out of scope.

    std::string result = async.get(); // Behavior is now undefined; crashing is likely.
    std::cout << result.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`

```cpp
struct MyClass : std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>
{
    std::string m_value{ "Hello, World!" };

    Task<std::string> RetrieveValueAsync()
    {
        auto lock_me = shared_from_this();

        co_await 5s; // resumes on thread pool
        co_return m_value;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to go is get hold of the `shared_ptr` in the coroutine.

```cpp
struct MyClass
{
    static auto make_shared()
    {
        auto result = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
        result->weak = result;
        return result;
    }
    std::weak_ptr<MyClass> weak{nullptr};
    std::string m_value{ "Hello, World!" };

    Task<std::string> RetrieveValueAsync()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<MyClass> strong = weak.lock();
        co_await 5s;
        co_return m_value;
    }
};
```